# I am trying to get the output in below nested dictionary format for the given input

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to get the output in the form of nested dictionary. I am practicing this for python automation for Network simulator. I tried but not able to achieve. Kindly someone help me on this.

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
Vlan30                 30.1.1.2        YES NVRAM  up                    up
Vlan306                192.168.25.3    YES NVRAM  up                    down
GigabitEthernet0/0     11.19.17.19     YES NVRAM  up                    up
Te1/0/3                unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Te1/0/21               unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Te1/0/35               unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
```

output should be in below format.

```
{'interface': {
               'vlan1': {
                   'name': 'vlan1',
                   'ip': 'unassigned',
                   'ok_status': 'YES',
                   'method': 'NVRAM',
                   'status': 'up',
                   'protocol': 'up',
                   },
               'vlan30': {
                   'name': 'vlan30',
                   'ip': '30.1.1.2',
                   'ok_status': 'YES',
                   'method': 'NVRAM',
                   'status': 'up',
                   'protocol': 'up',
                   }
              }
         }
```

Comment: Your expected output is already interpreted as a dictionary object, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place your input data in a text file (example `D:/test.txt`), following code will format it according to your specification:

```
comma_sep = ""
with open("D:/test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = [part for part in line.split(' ') if part != '']
        comma_sep += ','.join(parts)

lines = [item for item in comma_sep.split('\n')]

output_dict = {"interface": {}}

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if index == 0:
        continue
    # Compose each interface
    interface = {}
    for item_index, item in enumerate(line.split(',')):
        if item_index == 0:
            item = item.lower()
            interface = {item: {}}
            interface[item].update({'name': item})
            main_key = item
        elif item_index == 1:
            interface[main_key].update({'ip': item})
        elif item_index == 2:
            interface[main_key].update({'ok_status': item})
        elif item_index == 3:
            interface[main_key].update({'method': item})
        elif item_index == 4:
            interface[main_key].update({'status': item})
        elif item_index == 5:
            interface[main_key].update({'protocol': item})

    output_dict["interface"].update(interface)

print(output_dict)
```